# How to synchronize tsfiles with mod files in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: synchronized, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I am doing data synchronization in Apache IoTDB, all tsfiles with `mod` files cannot be synchronized. Why IoTDB produced these `mod` files, and how should I deal with this problem?